# How to access content of a file pass as an argument?

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming, and I want to access the content of a text file pass as an argument.

When I execute my program:

```
./cat 10 60 < dog.txt
```

And when I run a for loop to iterate the arguments, it doesn't print the file that I'm passing as an argument.

```
./cat
10
60
```

So, I'm assuming that it is not considered as an argument. But, is there a way to pass a filename as an argument the way I did(`./cat 10 60 < dog.txt`) and then access its content?

Thank you for the help,

Comment: You are redirecting `stdin` that way. Is that what you want?

Comment: Do you want the file name or the file content?

Comment: `10` and `60` are the arguments. What other files are you passing as arguments?

Comment: `dog.txt` is not an argument. The shell is redirecting standard input to the file.

Comment: `./cat 10 60 < dog.txt` is *redirecting* `dog.txt` into the `stdin` of the program. It does not make it it's argument. `./cat 10 60 dog.txt` does.

Comment: @luk2302 I want the content of the file to let say store it into an array

Comment: @EugeneSh. Can I access the standard input of the file to which I'm sending the content of `dog.txt`?

Comment: You can just read the contents of the file from `stdin`, the way you execute the program.

Comment: @Cheatah I'm really new to C, so I'm guessing that I read the content with `getc(stdin)`?

Comment: Or `fread` or `fgets` or any of the other function that deal with input from a `FILE *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<` is a [redirection operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) provided by your [shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/What-is-a-shell_003f.html).

This operator opens the file on its right-hand side for reading, and, by default, remaps the standard input (`stdin`) of your program to be this file.

It is also possible to specify which *file descriptor* to remap with the form:

```
program [n]< file
```

wherein *[n]* is a number. The typical mapping between UNIX *file descriptors* and C Standard Library [*streams*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/std_streams) is

- `0` - `stdin`
- `1` - `stdout`
- `2` - `stderr`

but it is possible to open other file descriptors, and have your program read from them with [`man 2 read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html).

---

Here's an example program. Note the differences between these two different sets of commands:

This

```
./a.out a b < file.txt
```

will print the strings `a` and `b` under the section listing the program arguments, and then it will print the contents of `file.txt`.

Whereas this

```
./a.out a b file.txt
```

will print the strings `a`, `b`, and `file.txt` under the section listing the program arguments, and then wait for you to type something in the terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    size_t line = 0;
    char buffer[256];
    
    puts("--- argv ---");
                             
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("arg #%d : %s\n", i, argv[i]);
                             
    puts("--- stdin ---");

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))
        printf("%4zu|%s", ++line, buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Unix system, every file has three standard file descriptors (numbers mapping to files)

0 - Stdin
1 - Stdout
2 - Stderr

When you use the redirect symbol (<), bash closes stdin, which normally reads from your keyboard, and remaps it to the file that you are redirecting from, dog.txt in this case.

You are correct that it is not passed in as an argument, but you can still get the data by using the *read* command to read from file 0

```
read(0, *buf, buf_size);
```

E: Barmar pointed out that you should use the [stdio](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/stdio_h.htm) library to read from the input, which is more standard

Comment: In standard C you should use stdio, not POSIX functions.